# Dependency problems with nginx

Tags: apt

I'm trying to install nginx, but I get the error message:

```
Get:1 http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ jessie/main nginx-common all 1.6.2-5+deb8u2 [86.7 kB]
Fetched 86.7 kB in 10s (8,617 B/s)
(Reading database ... 191089 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../nginx-common_1.6.2-5+deb8u2_all.deb ...
Unpacking nginx-common (1.6.2-5+deb8u2) over (1.6.2-5) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/nginx-common_1.6.2-5+deb8u2_all.deb (--unpack):
 unable to install new version of `/usr/share/man/man1/nginx.1.gz': Input/output error
```

I've tried to uninstall everyting to start all over, but it fails:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 nginx-full : Depends: nginx-common (= 1.6.2-5+deb8u2) but 1.6.2-5 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

I've tried to run the "apt-get -f install" as suggested, but that fails because of the "Input/output error" described above.

Comment: Did you try `apt-get update` before running `apt-get install nginx`.  Can you tell us the command(s) you've used?

Comment: Yes, I did an apt--get update. Tried a few other things, and at last I managed to uninstall and reinstall everything. Not really sure how ... :-/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Check you have enough free disk space using `df -h`
- If not, you'd need to expand the filesystem if the sd card capacity is larger than the existing filesystem. search for `raspi-config` on how to do that

Comment: Could have been the disk space that was the problem, but I'm not sure. I deleted some junk on the disk before I read your answer and checked the disk space. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @prograde  if an answer worked for you, it would nice to accept it by clicking the tick mark near it.